# merging xlsx files by day, month and time(not by year) in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 4 excel files(xlsx) that I want to merge\join, and there are from different years.
I want to merge them by day, month and the time.
I don't know how to exclude the year.
in the end, I want to get a table for the all 4 year by dd\mm and time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tjd3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the date into Day, Month and Year and then merge on Day and Month.

You split it with pandas DatetimeIndex:

```
df['Year'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df['Month'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['Day'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
```

In your case:

```
dfs = [data2014, data2015...]

for df in dfs:
    df['Year'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
    df['Month'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
    df['Day'] = DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
```

And then merge the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude the year you can use [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

```
df['D.T'] = df['D.T'].dt.strftime('%d-/%m %H:%M:%S')
df['D.T'].head()

0    01/09 00:00:00
1    01/09 00:10:00
2    01/09 00:20:00
3    01/09 00:30:00
4    01/09 00:40:00
Name: D.T, dtype: object
```

Now, it's just to merge your dataframes.